# Is there a way to set owner of Google Folder / Files through script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am the Owner of a File / Folder and want to set the owner of the File and Folder through script to somebody else. It is part of a bigger code where I go through all subfolders and files of a given folder and want to give the ownership to somebody else. Problem is that the command 'setOwner()' does not work.

I have tried with the command folder.setOwner(Email Address) and it gave me the error message 'Invalid argument (line x, file "Code")' Dismiss
'. Also I tried with the command folder.setOwner(User), got the same error message again.

```
 var rootfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
 rootfolder.setOwner("email@domain.com");  //line x
```

or

```
 var newOwner = DriveApp.getFileById(FileId).getOwner();
 var rootfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
 rootfolder.setOwner(newOwner); //line x
```

Note: 'FileId' is from a Public File

I also tried this Code, which worked. I got Email from Google Drive that the given folder was transfered from me to me.

```
 var rootfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
 rootfolder.setOwner(rootfolder.getOwner());
```

But I do not want to transfer it to myself, but to somebody else.

<s>(I tried it on my personal and on my GSuite Account to a personal & GSuite account & all possibilities in between, nothing works)</s>

Comment: Are the email addresses you are attempting to add located outside your G Suite organization, and [are you authorized to share files with it](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en) otherwise?

Comment: I tried it for inside and outside. I also tried it with my personal Google Account and all various ways you could do it, nothing works. And yes, I am authorized to set the Owner of my account to another.

Answer (score 1):

I am dumb, the answer is super simple. I cannot share outside of my GSuite Account. If I try to transfer the Ownership to a user inside of your GSuite Account then it works perfectly!

The code is 100% correct.